# join points with arrow and label

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

My data file is like this:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2 id1 id2 value

x1 y1 x2 y2 id1 id2 value

x1 y1 x2 y2 id1 id2 value
.
.
.
```

I would like to joint the two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2`) with an arrow goes from 1 to 2.

Also i would like to:

add near the point 1 "id1" and near the point 2 "id2"

add a label with value in the middle of the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `vectors` plotting style for the arrows and `label` to add all the labels:

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors t '', \
     '' using 1:2:5 with labels offset char 0,1 t '',\
     '' using 3:4:6 with labels offset char 0,1 t '',\
     '' using (0.5*($1+$3)):(0.5*($2+$4)):7 with labels offset char 0,1 t ''
```

Plotting `with vectors` requires the starting point an the arrow length, `$1` accesses the values of the first column for calculations, `($3-$1)` is the x-length of the arrow.
`offset char 0,1` puts the label at a vertical offset of one character height above the given point. For more help see `help vectors` and `help labels`.